# How to work with iOS background modes?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, background, swift2

I want to create an application similar to WhatsApp and Viber (maybe Skype), for iPhone starting from iOS 8.4, using swift 2.2. So I need to send https requests to my server every 30 seconds (I am using `NSURLSession), to show that my application is online and other contacts can see it. There is no problem with it if application is in active state, timer works perfectly and every 30 seconds. But I need application to work also in Inactive, Background, Suspended and Not running (if that even possible) modes, even if iPhone is sleeping. I just need to send little signal, thats all.
I already have this code:

```
func registerBackgroundTask() {
    backgroundTask = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler {
        [unowned self] in self.endBackgroundTask()
    }
    assert(backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
}

func endBackgroundTask() {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(backgroundTask)
    backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
}

func reinstateBackgroundTask() {
    if backgroundTask == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid {
        registerBackgroundTask()
    }
}

func functionToPerformOnBackground() {
    requestToServer()
}
```

This functions are called by timer in AppDelegate.swift like this:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

    //START BACKGROUND TIMER!!!
    if !timerForBackgroundRunning {
        timerForBackground = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(20, target: self, selector: "functionToPerformOnBackground", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        registerBackgroundTask()
        timerForBackgroundRunning = true            
    }
}
```

and

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    if timerForBackgroundRunning {
        timerForBackground.invalidate()
        if backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid {
            endBackgroundTask()
        }
        timerForBackgroundRunning = false
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly, but when iPhone is going to sleep, it stops to send requests. To force code work again I have to go in application again and then press Home Button on iPhone. I have tested Viber and WhatsApp and I can say that Whatsapp is working similar, but Viber knows how to solve this problem.
Can somebody help me, please?
I will be thankful for any help, advice or anything.
P.S. I have already seen this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-ios-swift-tutorial
Is is great but not complete.

Comment: Have you read the section "Implementing a VoIP App" in the App programming guide https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW27 ?

Comment: Ho, I haven't. Reasons: it is very big, it uses Objective C, it is quite hard. Will it help for me if I read it? I mean, is there a solution to my problem? Thank you for reply!

Comment: Yes, it will help you.  Apple has made specific accommodation in iOS for VoIP apps and that document describes what they are.  Who said that writing apps is supposed to be easy?

Comment: No, not easy, but, I suppose, without additional complications. In fact, I don't use VoIP, because this part was made like additional library for me, it is written on C++ and I don't have code for it. So I just need to send requests...